# Searching indexed spreadsheets from Windows 10 explorer “search”

Tags: windows-10, search, spreadsheet, openoffice, search-indexing

I have a client that used to use Windows 7, and was able to search directly from the Windows explorer (start menu) to find spreadsheets by searching a number that was on column B within. Now that they're using Windows 10, the search is not finding any information "indexed" within the spreadsheets or giving suggestions for what spreadsheets may contain that number.

I have adjusted "indexing options" to index all "properties and file contents" for extensions relating to spreadsheets such as .xls .xlsx .ods, etc.. All of them i have manually found, indexed, and rebuilt the windows index many times. Also, turned "find my files" to "enhanced" within the Settings>Windows Search.